# Stretch wide landscape table to fit page

Tags: tables, landscape

I am wondering if the following wide table can be stretched out to fit a larger portion of the page. The size of the table is okay, but it would be ideal to be a little larger. Any suggestions would be super!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \caption {\label{tab:Table 4 - MDI recursive prediction} This table demonstrates the MDI classification report for the individual corporate credit rating classes for an ET. Based on the balance between number of features and predictive performance in Table 3, precision, recall, F1 score and support are evaluated on 20 features for U.S. and global NonESG and ESG samples.}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}
    {\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccc}
        \toprule
        {} & {\thead{U.S. NonESG \\ precision}} & {\thead{U.S. NonESG \\ recall}} & {\thead{U.S. NonESG \\ F1 score}} & {\thead{U.S. NonESG \\ support}} & {\thead{U.S ESG \\ precision}} & {\thead{U.S ESG \\ recall}} & {\thead{U.S ESG \\ F1 score}} & {\thead{U.S ESG \\ support}} & {\thead{GL NonESG \\ precision}} & {\thead{GL NonESG \\ recall}} & {\thead{GL NonESG \\ F1 score}} & {\thead{GL NonESG \\ support}} & {\thead{GL ESG \\ precision}} & {\thead{GL ESG \\ recall}} & {\thead{GL ESG \\ F1 score}} & {\thead{GL ESG \\ support}} \\
        \midrule\addlinespace  
        AAA & 0.9766 & 0.9843 & 0.9804 & 127 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 55 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 34 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 27 \\
        AA+ & 0.9844 & 0.9403 & 0.9618 & 67 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9167 & 0.9565 & 0.9362 & 23 & 0.9333 & 0.7778 & 0.8485 & 18 \\
        AA & 0.9703 & 0.9729 & 0.9716 & 369 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 148 & 0.9254 & 0.9688 & 0.9466 & 64 & 0.9219 & 0.9833 & 0.9516 & 60 \\
        AA- & 0.9543 & 0.9730 & 0.9636 & 408 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 96 & 0.9815 & 0.9578 & 0.9695 & 166 & 1 & 0.9645 & 0.9819 & 169 \\
        A+ & 0.9700 & 0.9739 & 0.9719 & 995 & 0.9968 & 1 & 0.9984 & 309 & 0.9804 & 0.9709 & 0.9756 & 309 & 0.9619 & 0.9806 & 0.9712 & 309 \\
        A & 0.9696 & 0.9639 & 0.9667 & 1357 & 0.9684 & 0.9629 & 0.9656 & 350 & 0.9463 & 0.9559 & 0.9511 & 295 & 0.9353 & 0.9455 & 0.9403 & 275 \\
        A- & 0.9577 & 0.9583 & 0.9580 & 1464 & 0.9790 & 0.9689 & 0.9739 & 482 & 0.9618 & 0.9658 & 0.9638 & 730 & 0.9772 & 0.9646 & 0.9709 & 622 \\
        BBB+ & 0.9558 & 0.9663 & 0.9610 & 1901 & 0.9724 & 0.9830 & 0.9776 & 823 & 0.9716 & 0.9716 & 0.9716 & 1090 & 0.9748 & 0.9737 & 0.9743 & 914 \\
        BBB & 0.9613 & 0.9582 & 0.9597 & 2438 & 0.9758 & 0.9697 & 0.9727 & 956 & 0.9537 & 0.9683 & 0.9609 & 914 & 0.9674 & 0.9744 & 0.9709 & 821 \\
        BBB- & 0.9541 & 0.9508 & 0.9524 & 2031 & 0.9701 & 0.9726 & 0.9714 & 802 & 0.9592 & 0.9613 & 0.9603 & 930 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 754 \\
        BB+ & 0.9347 & 0.9474 & 0.9410 & 1406 & 0.9560 & 0.9613 & 0.9587 & 543 & 0.9434 & 0.9488 & 0.9461 & 527 & 0.9504 & 0.9637 & 0.9570 & 358 \\
        BB & 0.9597 & 0.9413 & 0.9504 & 1721 & 0.9415 & 0.9489 & 0.9452 & 509 & 0.9667 & 0.8906 & 0.9271 & 521 & 0.9474 & 0.9375 & 0.9424 & 288 \\
        BB- & 0.9467 & 0.9554 & 0.9510 & 2397 & 0.9712 & 0.9637 & 0.9674 & 524 & 0.9268 & 0.9552 & 0.9408 & 424 & 0.9474 & 0.9083 & 0.9274 & 218 \\
        B+ & 0.9351 & 0.9496 & 0.9423 & 2261 & 0.9728 & 0.9831 & 0.9779 & 473 & 0.9250 & 0.9250 & 0.9250 & 320 & 0.9106 & 0.9412 & 0.9256 & 119 \\
        B & 0.9423 & 0.9262 & 0.9342 & 1341 & 0.9490 & 0.9442 & 0.9466 & 197 & 0.9157 & 0.9373 & 0.9264 & 255 & 0.8830 & 0.8925 & 0.8877 & 93 \\
        B- & 0.9010 & 0.9151 & 0.9080 & 577 & 0.9655 & 0.8889 & 0.9256 & 63 & 0.9409 & 0.8925 & 0.9161 & 214 & 0.9833 & 0.9365 & 0.9593 & 63 \\
        CCC+ & 0.9136 & 0.8627 & 0.8874 & 233 & 0.9730 & 0.9730 & 0.9730 & 37 & 0.7843 & 0.8333 & 0.8081 & 48 & 0.8235 & 0.9333 & 0.8750 & 30 \\
        CCC & 0.8701 & 0.7976 & 0.8323 & 84 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 9 & 0.7857 & 0.9429 & 0.8571 & 35 & 0.8235 & 1 & 0.9032 & 14 \\
        CCC- & 0.8864 & 0.7800 & 0.8298 & 50 & 1 & 0.9412 & 0.9697 & 17 & 0.9231 & 1 & 0.9600 & 36 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\
        CC & 0.9762 & 0.8200 & 0.8913 & 50 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 11 & 0.9130 & 0.7 & 0.7925 & 30 & 0.875 & 0.7 & 0.7778 & 10 \\
        SD & 0.5556 & 0.7143 & 0.6250 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9231 & 1 & 0.9600 & 12 & 0.5 & 0.3333 & 0.4 & 3 \\
        D & 0.9485 & 0.8846 & 0.9154 & 104 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 0.8889 & 1 & 0.9412 & 32 & 0.8333 & 0.8333 & 0.8333 & 6 \\
        accuracy & 0.9506 & 0.9506 & 0.9506 & 0.9506 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9518 & 0.9518 & 0.9518 & 0.9518 & 0.9612 & 0.9612 & 0.9612 & 0.9612 \\
        macro avg & 0.9284 & 0.9153 & 0.9207 & 21388 & 0.9796 & 0.9731 & 0.9762 & 6408 & 0.9288 & 0.9410 & 0.9334 & 7009 & 0.9145 & 0.9052 & 0.9077 & 5177 \\
        weighted avg & 0.9507 & 0.9506 & 0.9506 & 21388 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 6408 & 0.9522 & 0.9518 & 0.9517 & 7009 & 0.9614 & 0.9612 & 0.9611 & 5177 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document example is uncomplete. Missing are most of preamble and `\begin{document}`. Please make it compilable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- reorganize columns header, that columns can become narrower
- use `S` column type (defined in `siunitx` package
- remove `\resizebox{...}{...}`, it make table almost unreadable,
  instead use `tabular*` with `\linewidth`  (which is in landscape equal to `\textheight`) width and reduce font size to `\small`

Based on guessing (in lack of information about your document preamble) see, if the following solution is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \caption {\label{tab:Table 4 - MDI recursive prediction} This table demonstrates the MDI classification report for the individual corporate credit rating classes for an ET. Based on the balance between number of features and predictive performance in Table 3, precision, recall, F1 score and support are evaluated on 20 features for U.S. and global NonESG and ESG samples.}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l 
                                 *{4}{*{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}S[table-format=4.0]}
                                 }
        \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{U.S. NonESG}} 
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{U.S. NonESG}}
                    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{GL NonESG}} 
                            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{GL ESG}}    \\                 
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \cmidrule(l){10-13}
    \cmidrule(l){14-17}
    & {\thead{precision}} & {\thead{recall}} & {\thead{F1 score}} & {\thead{support}}   
    & {\thead{precision}} & {\thead{recall}} & {\thead{F1 score}} & {\thead{support}}
    & {\thead{precision}} & {\thead{recall}} & {\thead{F1 score}} & {\thead{support}}
    & {\thead{precision}} & {\thead{recall}} & {\thead{F1 score}} & {\thead{support}}
                                                                    \\
        \midrule
AAA & 0.9766 & 0.9843 & 0.9804 & 127 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 55 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 34 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 27                         \\
AA+ & 0.9844 & 0.9403 & 0.9618 & 67 
    & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0 
    & 0.9167 & 0.9565 & 0.9362 & 23 
    & 0.9333 & 0.7778 & 0.8485 & 18                         \\
AA  & 0.9703 & 0.9729 & 0.9716 & 369 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 148 
    & 0.9254 & 0.9688 & 0.9466 & 64 
    & 0.9219 & 0.9833 & 0.9516 & 60                         \\
AA- & 0.9543 & 0.9730 & 0.9636 & 408 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 96 
    & 0.9815 & 0.9578 & 0.9695 & 166 
    & 1      & 0.9645 & 0.9819 & 169                        \\
A+  & 0.9700 & 0.9739 & 0.9719 & 995 
    & 0.9968 & 1      & 0.9984 & 309 
    & 0.9804 & 0.9709 & 0.9756 & 309 
    & 0.9619 & 0.9806 & 0.9712 & 309                        \\
A   & 0.9696 & 0.9639 & 0.9667 & 1357 
    & 0.9684 & 0.9629 & 0.9656 & 350 
    & 0.9463 & 0.9559 & 0.9511 & 295 
    & 0.9353 & 0.9455 & 0.9403 & 275                        \\
A-  & 0.9577 & 0.9583 & 0.9580 & 1464 
    & 0.9790 & 0.9689 & 0.9739 & 482 
    & 0.9618 & 0.9658 & 0.9638 & 730 
    & 0.9772 & 0.9646 & 0.9709 & 622                        \\
        \addlinespace
BBB+ 
    & 0.9558 & 0.9663 & 0.9610 & 1901 
    & 0.9724 & 0.9830 & 0.9776 & 823 
    & 0.9716 & 0.9716 & 0.9716 & 1090 
    & 0.9748 & 0.9737 & 0.9743 & 914                        \\
BBB & 0.9613 & 0.9582 & 0.9597 & 2438 
    & 0.9758 & 0.9697 & 0.9727 & 956 
    & 0.9537 & 0.9683 & 0.9609 & 914 
    & 0.9674 & 0.9744 & 0.9709 & 821                        \\
BBB- 
    & 0.9541 & 0.9508 & 0.9524 & 2031 
    & 0.9701 & 0.9726 & 0.9714 & 802 
    & 0.9592 & 0.9613 & 0.9603 & 930 
    & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 754                        \\
BB+ & 0.9347 & 0.9474 & 0.9410 & 1406 
    & 0.9560 & 0.9613 & 0.9587 & 543 
    & 0.9434 & 0.9488 & 0.9461 & 527 
    & 0.9504 & 0.9637 & 0.9570 & 358                        \\
BB  & 0.9597 & 0.9413 & 0.9504 & 1721 
    & 0.9415 & 0.9489 & 0.9452 & 509 
    & 0.9667 & 0.8906 & 0.9271 & 521 
    & 0.9474 & 0.9375 & 0.9424 & 288                        \\
BB- & 0.9467 & 0.9554 & 0.9510 & 2397 
    & 0.9712 & 0.9637 & 0.9674 & 524 
    & 0.9268 & 0.9552 & 0.9408 & 424 
    & 0.9474 & 0.9083 & 0.9274 & 218                        \\
B+  & 0.9351 & 0.9496 & 0.9423 & 2261 
    & 0.9728 & 0.9831 & 0.9779 & 473 
    & 0.9250 & 0.9250 & 0.9250 & 320 
    & 0.9106 & 0.9412 & 0.9256 & 119                        \\
B   & 0.9423 & 0.9262 & 0.9342 & 1341 
    & 0.9490 & 0.9442 & 0.9466 & 197 
    & 0.9157 & 0.9373 & 0.9264 & 255 
    & 0.8830 & 0.8925 & 0.8877 & 93                         \\
B-  & 0.9010 & 0.9151 & 0.9080 & 577 
    & 0.9655 & 0.8889 & 0.9256 & 63 
    & 0.9409 & 0.8925 & 0.9161 & 214 
    & 0.9833 & 0.9365 & 0.9593 & 63                         \\
        \addlinespace
CCC+ 
    & 0.9136 & 0.8627 & 0.8874 & 233 
    & 0.9730 & 0.9730 & 0.9730 & 37 
    & 0.7843 & 0.8333 & 0.8081 & 48 
    & 0.8235 & 0.9333 & 0.8750 & 30                         \\
CCC & 0.8701 & 0.7976 & 0.8323 & 84 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 9 
    & 0.7857 & 0.9429 & 0.8571 & 35 
    & 0.8235 & 1      & 0.9032 & 14                         \\
CCC- 
    & 0.8864 & 0.7800 & 0.8298 & 50 
    & 1      & 0.9412 & 0.9697 & 17 
    & 0.9231 & 1      & 0.9600 & 36 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 6                          \\
CC  & 0.9762 & 0.8200 & 0.8913 & 50 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 11 
    & 0.9130 & 0.7    & 0.7925 & 30 
    & 0.875  & 0.7    & 0.7778 & 10                         \\
        \addlinespace
SD  & 0.5556 & 0.7143 & 0.6250 & 7 
    & 0      & 0      & 0      & 0 
    & 0.9231 & 1      & 0.9600 & 12 
    & 0.5    & 0.3333 & 0.4    & 3                          \\
D   & 0.9485 & 0.8846 & 0.9154 & 104 
    & 1      & 1      & 1      & 4      
    & 0.8889 & 1      & 0.9412 & 32 
    & 0.8333 & 0.8333 & 0.8333 & 6                          \\
        \midrule
accuracy 
    & 0.9506 & 0.9506 & 0.9506 & {0.9506} 
    & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & {0.9708} 
    & 0.9518 & 0.9518 & 0.9518 & {0.9518} 
    & 0.9612 & 0.9612 & 0.9612 & {0.9612}                   \\
macro avg 
    & 0.9284 & 0.9153 & 0.9207 & {21388} 
    & 0.9796 & 0.9731 & 0.9762 & {6408} 
    & 0.9288 & 0.9410 & 0.9334 & {7009} 
    & 0.9145 & 0.9052 & 0.9077 & {5177}                     \\
weighted avg 
    & 0.9507 & 0.9506 & 0.9506 & {21388}  
    & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & 0.9708 & {6408}   
    & 0.9522 & 0.9518 & 0.9517 & {7009}   
    & 0.9614 & 0.9612 & 0.9611 & {5177}                       \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When I copy, the headers e.g. U.S. NonESG and the precision, recall etc. are bolded. Any reason why this would occur?

Comment: @oceanbeach96, yes, you use different document preamble that is in my MWE. In it you have somewhere a `\renewcommand\theadfont{ \bfseries ...}`. Remove it, if you not like to gave bold fonts in column headers.